# Counting data from two tables and grouping it all by name that exists in both tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to merge two tables that I have, both of them have the same name in them. Going to use it so corresponding ticket number can have few requests, and also few files in it

```
Table1 that is my main table      Table 2 that I want to join
+----+------+-------+-------+     +----+------+-------+
| ID | Name | Info1 | Info2 |     | ID | Name | Info1 |
+----+------+-------+-------+     +----+------+-------+
|  0 | L01  | blah  | blah  |     |  0 | L01  | blah  |
|  1 | L02  | blah2 | blah2 |     |  1 | L01  | blah  |
|  2 | L02  | blah3 | blah3 |     |  2 | L03  | blah  |
|  3 | L03  | Blah3 | blah3 |     |  3 | L04  | blah  |
|  4 | L04  | Blah4 | blah4 |     |  4 | L04  | blah  |
+----+------+-------+-------+     +----+------+-------+
```

> Then I use select to group it like this

```
+------+-------------+
| Name | Count(Name) |
+------+-------------+
| L01  |           1 |
| L02  |           2 |
| L03  |           1 |
| L04  |           1 |
+------+-------------+
```

And my goal is to make something like this

```
+------+-------------+--------------------+
| Name | Count(Name) | Count(table2.Name) |
+------+-------------+--------------------+
| L01  |           1 |                  2 |
| L02  |           2 |                  0 |
| L03  |           1 |                  1 |
| L04  |           1 |                  2 |
+------+-------------+--------------------+
```

any suggestions? code I tried so far on my existing project, `NR_REKLAMACJI is my Name from Table 1, this code was working when I only counted the number of Names in this particular table:

```
SELECT
  `NR_REKLAMACJI`,
  COUNT(NR_REKLAMACJI) AS 'ilosc reklamowanego towaru',
  CONCAT(klienci.IMIE, ' ', klienci.NAZWISKO) AS 'Klient',
  CONCAT(users.IMIE, ' ', users.NAZWISKO) AS 'Osoba zajmująca się',
  DOK_FV,
  klienci.NAZWA_FIRMY,
  DATA

FROM
  `rtransportowa`
  INNER JOIN klienci ON ID_R = klienci.ID_KLIENTA
  INNER JOIN users ON ID_U = users.ID_USER

group by
  NR_REKLAMACJI
```

Comment: Your sample data , expected output and code don't tie up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join two subqueries result and construct a result as you want on basis of a left-join:

```
SELECT t1.`Name` as `Name`, t1.count AS `count(Name)`, IFNULL(t2.count, 0) AS `count(table2.Name)` 
FROM (SELECT `Name`, count(*) AS count FROM tbl1 GROUP BY `Name`) t1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT `Name`, count(*) AS count FROM tbl2 GROUP BY `Name`) t2 ON t1.`Name` = t2.`Name`;
```

Comment: This won't show `L02` count. maybe with `LEFT JOIN` can

Comment: I have updated my answer to use `LEFT JOIN` and if t2count is null then it will return 0.

Comment: This assumes that there every name in table 2 has a matching name in table 1

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes obvious, because OP has mentioned that table1 is main table. So no entry will be present in table2 (which isn't in table 1) logically.

Comment: Thank you BilalSiddiqui and @tcadidot0 , that was it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use joining two table  as one table

```
    select tb1.Name,
    CASE WHEN tb1_Count_Name IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE tb1_Count_Name  END AS tb1_Count_Name,      
    CASE WHEN tb2_Count_Name IS NULL THEN '0'ELSE tb2_Count_Name   END AS tb2_Count_Name from 
    (select DISTINCT Name as Name,Count(Name) as tb1_Count_Name from [dbo].[Table_1] as t1 group by t1.Name) as tb1 left join 
    (select DISTINCT Name as Name ,Count(Name) as tb2_Count_Name from [dbo].[Table_2]as t2  group by t2.Name )as tb2 on tb1.Name=tb2.Name
```